# ReadFile Timeout for inter-byte delay time

Tags: c++, c, windows, serial-port

I want `ReadFile()` with serial communication device to return when at least one byte is received or when being timeout .

As i have looked for about timeout for `ReadFile()`.

Most of people mention `SetCommTimeouts()` and `overlapped I/O`

But `SetCommTimeouts()` doesn't return, a byte is received though, until being timeout.

And `overlapped I/O(GetOverlappedResult)` also doesn't satisfy my requirement. right?

And However i know `GetOverlappedResultEx()` seems to support that, using `DWORD dwMilliseconds` parameter, I don't want to use `EX` series functions.

Is there any way ?

Comment: "I don't want to use EX series functions.": why? Many core Win32 APIs end in `Ex`.

Comment: you could use the 'select' function, with a timeout then it returns when either a char is available or the timeout occurs.  it returns a value that indicates which happened.

Comment: But as it know in windows, select is only for socket. No ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the asynchronous version of the function, by specifying `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`.

When a timeout is reached you can call `CancelIo` with the file handle.

```
HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, TizReadFile, tizHandle, 0, 0);
WaitForSingleObject(hThread, 2);
CancelIo(tizHandle);
...
DWORD WINAPI TizReadFile(HANDLE &tizHandle)
{
    DWORD dwRead = 0;
    if(0 == ReadFile(tizHandle, g_globalBuffer, dwWant2Read, &dwRead, 0))
        return GetLastError();
    return 1;
}
```